# convert js into typescript into angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

Below code is working fine in javascript. But when i tried the same in Angular 8 I am getting lot of error

```
const signUpButton = document.getElementById('signUp');
const signInButton = document.getElementById('signIn');
const container = document.getElementById('container');

signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add('right-panel-active');
});

signInButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.remove('right-panel-active');
});
}
```

Errors
signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
~
error TS1003: Identifier expected.

```
    69 signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                                         ~~~~~~~
    Parameter declaration expected.

    69 signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                                                ~
    Parameter declaration expected.

    69 signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                                                  ~
    error TS1005: ';' expected.

    71 });
            ~
    error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

please let me know how to convert this into Typescript

Comment: please share your tsconfig file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, It's better to not use eventListeners rather use event binding in your HTML code.

Your HTML will look something like :

```
<input type="button" name="" id="signUp" (click)="signUp()">
<input type="button" name="" id="signIn" (click)="signIn()">
```

and in TS file :

```
signUp() {
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.classList.add('right-panel-active');
}

signIn() {
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.classList.remove('right-panel-active');
}
```

Read more on --> https://angular.io/guide/event-binding

Answer (score -1):

Try this in `.ts` file as is, there were one extra curly braces in your code,

```
const signUpButton = document.getElementById('signUp');
const signInButton = document.getElementById('signIn');
const container = document.getElementById('container');

signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add('right-panel-active');
});

signInButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.remove('right-panel-active');
});
```